# MS Access VBA Ranged Dates with BETWEEN or single entry with in Text Boxes

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm looking for some assistance on this  Look up code I managed to put together.

```
If Me.txtStartDate > "" And Me.txtEndDate > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "[CompletionDate] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtStartDate & "# AND #" & Me.txtEndDate & "#"

ElseIf Me.txtStartDate > "" And Me.txtEndDate Is Nothing Then
varWhere = varWhere & "[CompletionDate] = """" & Me.txtStartDate & " * "" And ""

ElseIf Me.txtStartDate Is Nothing And Me.txtEndDate > "" Then
MsgBox "Please Input a Start Date", vbOKOnly, Error

End If
```

I feel like the code itself is self explanatory of my goals. However I'm wanting to allow the user to input into `Me.txtStartDate` & `Me.txtEndDate` giving the range. Also, Allowing the user to just input into `Me.txtStartDate` for a single date.  I have attempted combining the two Along with a message box if they input into end date alone.

Its not working for me, I can get either or working.

My Question is "How do I combine these three statements, so they work in a conditional statement way?"

Anything helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Side comment: You should look into using date controls instead of textboxes as it will help with ensuring the variables are actual dates, and also check to make sure the start date isnt after the end date.

Comment: What is actually occurring when you run this code? An error? No results? I'm assuming that you use this as a filter to a SQL query somewhere down the line, or a DLookup, or something. More context/information is needed.

Comment: @PatJones Just the Between Statement works I would like for it to choose between the 3 depending on the user's actions. Its a Search Form using text Boxes.

Comment: In a search form with date boxes, you should default dates into both to and from dates. I personally tend to use the first day of the current month as the txtFromDate, and today's date as the txtEndDate. Format both boxes to short dates. This avoids you running blank checks, or makes it highly unlikely a null date would be entered. Simply check both controls for non dates and exit sub.

Comment: Still need the # delimiter for the second criteria and no wildcard. Wildcard is only useful with LIKE operator. Why the " And " appended to the second criteria but not with the BETWEEN AND version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  I like to use datepickers.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.DTPickerStart.DefaultValue = "Date()"
Me.DTPickerEnd.DefaultValue = "Date()"
```

Then I'd do something like this.

```
If (Nz(Me.Me.txtStartDate.Value) = "") Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Start Date.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf (Nz(Me.txtEndDate.Value) = "") Then
    MsgBox "Please select a End Date.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
Else
    DoCmd.OpenReport "XYZRpt", acViewPreview
    Or you could do..
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Passthroughquery"  that links to an SQL procedure.  I'm not 
    sure what you're trying to do though.  
End If
```